# Separate self-cited papers in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to split my bibliography into two parts.

First, list all the papers in which I'm one of the authors from [1] to [n].

Second, list all the other papers with `plain` style [AA00] ... [ZZ16]:

```
\bibliography{biblio} 
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

Do you know which is the easiest way to do it?

Also, I would like my name to be underlined in all my papers in the references.

Comment: This sounds like a job for [`biblatex`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex/biblatex.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered in http://texblog.org/2012/10/22/multiple-bibliographies-with-biblatex/.

with keyword=own.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This help a lot.
I still have one problem: if I use
\usepackage[sorting=none, backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
I get the same style for both bibliographies, while I would like to have one with numbers and one with [AA00]. Do you know how to change it?

Comment: unfortunately not.

Comment: Why not use a comment?